# Stripe Fee in connected accounts

Tags: stripe-payments

We are working with connected accounts to generate a subscription.

Works fine, but the stripe fee should be paid by the main account, not the connected account.

Example:

Subscription with 100 EUR

Stripe Fee (1.4% + 0.25 EUR) = 1.40 EUR + 0.25 EUR = 1.65 EUR

The 1.65 EUR are payed by the connected account and **should** be payed by the main account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the Fund flow. If you are using [Direct Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#flow-of-funds-with-fees), it's expected that Connected Account would bear the fee.

You can either

1. Use [Destination Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#flow-of-funds-app-fee) (with Express/Custom) instead.
2. Keep using Direct Charge, but lower your application fee to cover the Stripe fee for your Connected Account.

Looking at [how those fund flows are designed](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#types), I believe 1 is recommended. Also you should email Stripe Support and they will explain better than community